# How to find the equation of this ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections

If you have four points $A(4,10),\; B(-4,10),\; C(-4,-10),\; D(4,-10)$ and an ellipse passes $A,B,C$ and $D$ points and these points form a rectangle inside this ellipse.

How to find the equation of that ellipse?

Comment: The general equation of an ellipse is $$(x-x_0)^2/a^2+(y-y_0)^2/b^2=1$$

Comment: There's not a unique solution.  The circle of radius $\sqrt{4^2+10^2}$ passes through those points.

Comment: $(\frac {x}{4})^2 + (\frac {y}{10})^2 = 2$ is an equation that will work.

Comment: @DougM How did you find that b=2 ?

Comment: Four points are not enough to determine a unique ellipse. Even if you require that it be in standard position, they don’t provide enough constraints due to the symmetries among them.

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the comments but it has a graphic.
What does the graphic convey?

[image]